# Largest memory space that can be addressed

Tags: binary

I was asked the following question on an assignment, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

"What is the largest memory space (i.e. program) that can be addressed by processors with the following number of address bits?
(c) 24 bits"

I put 011111111111111111111111 (0 followed by 23 1s). Is this correct? If not, how do I find the answer to this question? You can use a different amount of bits for an example if you want to. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `011111111111111111111111` is not the correct answer.  I'm assuming that you were calculating the largest number that can be represented by a signed 24 bit integer.

Memory address would be always unsigned so the answer is the number items that can be represented in 24 bits, which is `2^24` or `1000000000000000000000000` which is 1 followed by 24 zeros (assuming that I counted correctly) - since the address range includes `0` and goes to `1111111111111111111111` (24 1's).

Answer (score 3):

2^N bytes, where N is number of bits in the address space.

For example, the 8088 processor had a 20 bit address space and so it could address 2^20 bytes = 1 MB.

Address space is unsigned so N is full number of bits, not number of bits minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

An address in programming is usually something that represents a location in memory.
You can always represent as many locations as there are unique numbers.

How many locations can you address with a range from 1 to 10? 10.
How many locations can you address with a range from 1 to 2^24? 2^24.

So you can represent 2^24 locations and you didn't answer correctly.

Comment: off-by-one: "0 to 9" would be much better range than "1 to 10"... Also 2^24 requires 25 bits...

Comment: I thought about start counting from 0 but that would've made the point unclear as I would have needed to put a `-1` somewhere or a `<`. So I didn't. Also I don't see why I should need 25 bits for `1 <= x <= 2^24`?

Comment: To me saying "location with address `0000` will be called `1`" is somewhat confusing... but I was born with C where arrays are 0-based, unlike modern people - so you sample may be fine this way. 2^24 itself requires 25 bits - when represented, but again - your sample is 1-based which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the wrong track.

Memory addresses are unsigned, so the size of the address space is 2^24 bytes, or 16Mb.

Answer (score 1):

If you had 2 bits you could go from 00 to 11, 00, 01, 10, 11, four addresses.  Four is 1 with two zeros 0.  Two address bits one with two zeros is the number of addresses or 2 to the power 2.  3 bits 0b1000 or 8 addresses 2 to the power 3, 4 bits 0b10000 or 16 addresses, 2 to the power 4 and so on to whatever number of bits you want.